# How many cycles, $C_{4}$, does the graph $Q_{n}$ contain?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

> Let $n \geq 2$ be an integer. How many cycles of length $4$ (that is, subgraphs isomorphic to $C_4$) does the hypercube graph $Q_n$ contain?

**Examples:** For $n = 2$, the hypercube graph $Q_2$ is a single $4$-cycle, so the answer in this case is $1$. For $n = 3$, the hypercube graph $Q_3$ is a cube, and the answer is $6$.

I was told that $n$-dimensional cube graphs, $Q_{n}$ can be represented by binary but how can that help me approach this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many $C_4$s pass through a given vertex $v$? There are  two edges in this cycle through
$v$. There are $n$ edges through $v$ so $\binom {n}2$
pairs of edges. Once we have these two edges there is
just one way to complete the $C_4$. Don't forget there are $2^n$
vertices overall and each $C_4$ features four of them.

Answer (score 1):

If we label the vertices with strings of $0$'s and $1$'s, edges of the cube connect vertices differing in a single position (Hamming distance $1$).

To choose the vertices of a $4$-cycle, start with any binary number you like. Choose one position to change, and then another. To close the cycle, you're forced to change the original position back, and finally the second position back. For example,

$$
11001 \overset{\color{red}2}{\to} 
1\color{red}0001 \overset{\color{blue}4}{\to} 
100\color{blue}11 \overset{\color{red}2}{\to} 
1\color{red}1011 \overset{\color{blue}4}{\to}
110\color{blue}01 
$$

This suggests:

- We pick one of the $2^n$ vertices
- We pick some subset $\{i,j\}$ of positions to be changed, out of the possibilities $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.

But of course, it can't be that easy: surely there are multiple ways to choose the same $4$-cycle! Looking at our example above, we could have started with any of the four vertices as a starting point, but we would have had to make the same choice of positions to change. That suggests we've overcounted by a factor of $4$.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another way to look at it: $Q_n$ is a two-dimensional projection of an $n$-dimensional hypercube, so each distinct $C_4$ in $Q_n$ is a face of the $n$-dimensional hypercube.

When $n\ge 3$ the $n$-dimensional cube satisfies the generalized Euler polytope formula
$$
V-E+F=1+(-1)^{n-1}.
$$
For $Q(n)$ we have $V=2^n$ and $E=n2^{n-1}$ so that
$$
F=n2^{n-1}-2^n+1+(-1)^{n-1}.
$$

As to how $Q_n$ is represented with binary strings: Each vertex in $Q_n$ corresponds with each of the possible $n+1$-digit binary string and an edge exists between two vertices if their corresponding strings differ in exactly one digit.

Comment: It may be intuitive, but is it easy to actually prove that every $C_4$ on $Q_n$ is the $1$-skeleton of a face of the hypercube? (I'm not even 100% convinced that it is true.)

Comment: Actually, now I think this is completely wrong, because it does not account for faces of higher order than $2$.

Comment: What do you mean by faces of higher order than 2? Certainly all faces of a hypercube are 4-cycles. Now consider the binary string labeling of $Q_n$. An edge exists between two vertices whose binary labeling differ by exactly one element which seems to imply that all edges form the boundary of faces. For there to exist a 4-cycle that is not on a face boundary, an edge would have to exist that connects two vertices that differ in more that one spot, which is impossible.

Comment: Geometrically, $Q_n $ is an n-dimensional polytope. It has vertices, edges, 2-faces, 3-faces, etc., all the way up to n-faces.

Comment: I am not saying you are wrong, but perhaps you could demonstrate demonstrate a 4-cycle in some $Q_n$ that is not a face.

Comment: Never mind. The accepted answer is correct and mine is incorrect.

Comment: What I'm saying is that Euler's formula for an $n$-dimensional polytope contains more than $V$, $E$ and $F$ when $n > 2$.

Comment: I do see your point now. Thank you.